# Filling in a column according to several arguments

Tags: r, na

An example is worth a thousand words:

```
> head(regi_T)
         Date  Qobs Ptot Fsol  Temp  PE  Q_mm     J  JY
62 1957-01-01 0.003  0.0  -99  -7.0 0.0 1.039 01-01 001
63 1957-01-02 0.002  0.8  -99 -11.0 0.0 0.926 02-01 002
64 1957-01-03 0.002  0.0  -99  -7.0 0.0 0.907 03-01 003
65 1957-01-04 0.002  0.0  -99   3.0 0.5 0.879 04-01 004
66 1957-01-05 0.002  1.3  -99  -1.0 0.2 0.746 05-01 005
67 1957-01-06 0.002  9.9  -99  -0.5 0.3 0.642 06-01 006

> head(regime_T)
   j        x
1 001 -1.0150943
2 002 -1.7000000
3 003 -0.8830189
4 004 -1.4452830
5 005 -2.3566038
6 006 -1.3603774
```

I need to fill in the `Regi_T$Temp` column WHEN it's equal to NA BY `regime_T$x`according to the number of the day (so `regi_T$JY` and `regime_T$j`).

Example : There is a NA the 110th day in `regi_T`, I need to get the value of the 110th in `regime_T` and replace the NA by this new value.

Anyone has an idea?

I tried which follows:

```
id <- which(is.na(regi_T$Temp))         
day.na <- regi_T[id,9]
id_temp <- which(regime_T$j==day.na)
regime_T[day.na,2]
```

Which is kind of working but there are NA in my results (see below the beginning) which I don't know where they come from....

```
 [1] -0.6811321 -0.9773585  5.0867925  5.0867925  6.8547170  NA -6.8153846 17.5433962 17.2622642 17.1792453
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

regi_T %>% 
  left_join(regime_T, by = c('JY' = 'j')) %>%
  mutate(nas_replaced = coalesce(T, x))
```

You can then use `select` to use get only the columns you'd like. `coalesce` uses the first non-na value in the given arguments.